# How do I enable SEANDROID ENFORCING over adb inside TWRP?

Tags: adb, twrp, usb-debugging, command-line, seandroid

When I boot into TWRP Recovery, it says,

```
RECOVERY IS NOT SEANDROID ENFORCING
```

but when I run `sestatus`, it tells me

```
SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /sys/fs/selinux
Current mode:                   permissive
Mode from config file:          permissive
Policy version:                 26
Policy from config file:        sepolicy
```

How do I set the SEANDROID ENFORCING?

Comment: This warning seems to be Samsung devices specific mostly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that what that warning is referring too is the SEAndroid **ENFORCING**, you can change that with `setenforce`

```
$ setenforce Enforcing
$ sestatus
SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /sys/fs/selinux
Current mode:                   enforcing
Mode from config file:          enforcing
Policy version:                 26
Policy from config file:        sepolicy
```

You can also test this with `getenforce`

```
$ getenforce 
Enforcing
```

Comment: I reckon that this doesn't change SEA status permanently and hence will not eliminate the warning on boot?

Comment: @AndyYan no, it will not. While that's another question I have, I'm inclined to think persistence is different and a follow up.

Comment: Actually, i'm stuck on boot splash, the more I read about this, the more I'm convinced it has nothing to do with my boot splash.

Comment: Whatever applies to the recovery has nothing to do with the main OS. If you hit a bootloop/stuck with the OS then no point in messing with the recovery itself.

Comment: If we're assuming that the recovery was to do all its jazz while not in SEANDROID ENFORCING, I would agree. Anyway, in trying to trouble shoot it there are hordes of people that disagree with us online, too many for to discard all that testimony without looking into it.

Comment: All Samsung devices I've played with have non-SEA-enforcing recoveries and that doesn't affect how they work. In fact I'm guessing that they work well precisely because SEA-permissive means lax security measures and grants it full capability of tampering with the device (though I've never seen an official confirmation of this).

Comment: We're on the same team, I agree. I just didn't know much about the SE-A Enforcing stuff, and wanted to learn more, now I know how to turn it on, and I can't see how a more restrictive policy can cause an error.

Comment: https://source.android.com/security/selinux/   first has several tutorials this is the overview. More info in menu the left and several resources at the bottom      https://su.chainfire.eu/#selinux this is interesting the battle between the two

Comment: @BoLawson saw that, but that's more about what SELinux is so I didn't put that link in here. It also doesn't address how SELinux is supposed to operate with a recovery. Or, how you would restrict a recovery whose goal is literally to override or wipe the OS.

Comment: Start here breaks down the difference: http://hsc.com/DesktopModules/DigArticle/Print.aspx?PortalId=0&ModuleId=1215&Article=66 as far as custom recovery it is not really an issue. People tend to focus on it more than need when it comes to recovery. I guessing the colorful writing. Most of the times I've seen it its from flashing the wrong variant or using an SU binary injector script for an older android version. From people not paying attention to patches. S.E. stands for security enhanced to help on your research when it comes to older documents.